# How to extract Freebase Data Dump for a particular topic

Tags: rdf, freebase, musicbrainz

I want to extract music data from the freebase data dumps. (http://www.freebase.com/music)

Once I have the data dump how to I extract say the following properties http://www.freebase.com/music/recording?schema=

Will a better approach be get all songs and then fetch relevant information from it? If this is a good approach how should I go about extracting it?

Answer (score 7):

```
zgrep $'\tns:music\.recording' freebase-rdf-{date}.gz | gzip > freebase-filtered.gz
```

should get you started.  Depending on what other information you want, you may need to expand on it.