# How can I extract Name and Type of all the entities in Freebase?

Tags: google-api, freebase, named-entity-recognition, freebase-acre

i am trying to extract the all the Named entities and its type in Freebase dump.

I have looked at 
[How to extract Freebase Data Dump for a particular topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594646/how-to-extract-freebase-data-dump-for-a-particular-topic) 
But i didn't get actual named entities in Freebase dump.

I'am trying to get the information something like this,
Name: Barak Obama type: Person
Name: New York type: City etc..

Freebase is already having all these entities in its database but i didn't find any of Freebase API or Google API to list all the entities and its type.

Could you please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data dump format is described [here](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data).  It's changed some since I wrote the answer that you reference, but the basic principals are still the same.

The [MQLread](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/mql-overview) and [Search](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview) APIs can both be used to filter Freebase topics to a specific type (e.g. the /people/person type).  Topics can have multiple types, but if what you want is the classic NER types, then the first thing to do is probably filter by the desired types since there are "only" about 3 million people in Freebase out of the tens of millions of topics.

Freebase contains a lot more information than just the name which would be useful in an NER task, so you might want to take a step back and think about what other properties you might want to extract as well.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply.  I was looking for Topic to category mapping, finally am able to get such mapping using WikiDump. Where i can get category/categories for each Wikipedia title. Reference: http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39

Comment: I'm not sure which DBpedia file on that page you ended up using, but the same information is available from the Freebase dumps.  DBpedia & Freebase have different strengths & weaknesses, so it's worth looking at both.

Comment: I was implementing Query Classification using wikipedia dataset, in the beginning i had plan to get Category graph from freebase since it has more dataset. Finally we decided to go with wiki category graph. In dbpedia i have used http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39#articles-categories and http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39#categories-skos files.