# Downloading and using specific database from Freebase

Tags: freebase, data-dump

I would like to download a part of the Freebase database (specifically the `/film/film` data dump).
Currently I'm only seeing the option to download the entire data dump: https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

Is there any option to download a specific data dump? 
How to access the data dump downloaded and use it in my own database?

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer the option to download a specific domain (e.g /film) subset of Freebase as there was in the past.  You'll need to download the full data and filter it to what you need.  Note that even if you are principally interested in Film, you'll probably also need bits of other domains (e.g. /location) to be able to understand filming locations, actors birth places, etc.

Comment: can you please explain how to extract the wanted subsets and load them to my database? (MySQL)

Comment: There are a bunch of possibilities - use your favorite ETL framework/tool, use your favorite programming language, use grep/sed/etc Unix command line tools.  Pick the approach that best fits your skills and interests.

Comment: I understand that there are various tools to achieve my goal. I'm asking for a specific example.

Comment: @TomMorris Will this not work anymore? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594646/how-to-extract-freebase-data-dump-for-a-particular-topic You wrote it back in May 2013.

Comment: @EllieKesselman I think the format has changed slightly since I wrote that, but the basic strategy should still work.  The OP was asking (as I understood it) about a way to get a subset without first downloading the entire dump (in addition to asking to program a solution for him for free).